# Расположение html элементов

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите, как решить на js/jquery (неважно) такую задачку:
Имеются элементы (например, div) разные по высоте. Нужно расположить их в порядке убывания. Я смог высчитать высоту каждого на js:

```
let biggestHeight = 0;
let divCHild = document.querySelectorAll('div.child');
divCHild.forEach(function(element, index){
            console.log('div ' + index + ' height  = ' + element.offsetHeight + 'px');
            biggestHeight = element.offsetHeight > biggestHeight ? element.offsetHeight : 
            biggestHeight;
            });

console.log('biggestHeight = ' + biggestHeight + 'px');
```

**Спасибо!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У массивов есть встроенный метод сортировки [.sort( функция )](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) — вызывая функцию для определенных пар элементов `(a, b)` — если для них функция возвращает отрицательное число, ставит `a` под меньшим индексом, чем `b`, если положительное — наоборот, у `b` индекс будет меньше, чем у `a`. Вернет `0` — элементы останутся на своих местах.

Коллекция HTML-элементов — не массив. Чтобы использовать для них sort, можно заранее превратить коллекцию в обычный массив ( [Function.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) )

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div.child');

sort_by_height(divs);

function sort_by_height(elems) {

  let sorted_elems = [].slice.call(elems).sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.clientHeight - a.clientHeight;
  });
  
  sorted_elems.forEach(function(el) {
    el.parentNode.appendChild(el);
  });
  
}
```

```css
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #a22;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="child" style="height: 15px;"></div>
<div class="child" style="height: 150px;"></div>
<div class="child" style="height: 75px;"></div>
<div class="child" style="height: 65px;"></div>
<div class="child" style="height: 115px;"></div>
<div class="child" style="height: 125px;"></div>
<div class="child" style="height: 45px;"></div>
```

Более "свежий" вариант кода:

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div.child');

sort_by_height(divs);

function sort_by_height(elems) {
  [...elems].sort( (a, b) => b.clientHeight - a.clientHeight )
            .forEach( e => e.parentNode.appendChild(e) );  
}
```

```css
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #a22;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="child" style="height: 15px;"></div>
<div class="child" style="height: 150px;"></div>
<div class="child" style="height: 75px;"></div>
<div class="child" style="height: 65px;"></div>
<div class="child" style="height: 115px;"></div>
<div class="child" style="height: 125px;"></div>
<div class="child" style="height: 45px;"></div>
```

- [[...spread] оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [Стрелочные => функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

---

Касаемо вашего кода: Вы определяете максимальный размер блока, но ничего не делаете с самим блоком. Если пойти по вашему варианту, нужно помимо максимальной высоты, в дополнительной переменной хранить и элемент с этой высотой, после каждого цикла удалить максимальный блок из коллекции и запустить тот же цикл для оставшихся блоков.

Порядок элементов nodeList нельзя менять, поэтому коллекцию всё также придется предварительно превратить в массив.

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div.child');

let arr = [].slice.call(divs);

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

  for (let j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
    // arr[i] — первый элемент в текущем цикле.

    if (arr[i].clientHeight < arr[j].clientHeight) {
      // первый элемент меньше какого-то j-того? Меняем их местами

      [ arr[i], arr[j] ] = [ arr[j], arr[i] ];
    }

  } // В конце цикла arr[i] уже гарантированно будет самым большим
    // среди элементов от i до arr.length

  arr[i].parentNode.appendChild( arr[i] );
  
} // На следующей итерации найденный "большой" arr[i] не будет тронут,
  // т.к. следующий цикл начнется i++, от j = i;
```

```css
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #a22;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="child" style="height: 15px;"></div>
<div class="child" style="height: 150px;"></div>
<div class="child" style="height: 75px;"></div>
<div class="child" style="height: 65px;"></div>
<div class="child" style="height: 115px;"></div>
<div class="child" style="height: 125px;"></div>
<div class="child" style="height: 45px;"></div>
```

P.s. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLq7nB9bV0M&t=20m50s — три варианта сортировки, можете попробовать реализовать их на JS )

Comment: OPTIMUS PRIME, это то, что было нужно!! Спасибо огромное и плюс Вам в карму! -)